# PowerShell any element of array ends with any element in another array

Tags: powershell

I have a list1 of filenames and a list2 of FullNames (with path)

I need to extract all elements in list2 existing in list1. In plain english, all files listed in both sides, given with full path

I have tried

```
$filenames = @('index.jsp','index1.jsp', 'index2.jsp')
$fullpaths = Get-ChildItem -rec . | where { ! $_.PSIsContainer }
$common = $fullpaths | Where { $p = $_.FullName; foreach ($n in $filenames) { $p -match $($n + "$") } }
$common | foreach { Write-Output $_ }
```

But it outputs all files in .

How can I properly use **Where** in order to match one element against all the elements in the other list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you meant something like that

```
  $filenames = @('index.jsp','index1.jsp', 'index2.jsp')
  $common = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File | where Name -In $filenames
  $common.FullName
```

Comment: @marsze add -File :D

Comment: thanks for changing the requirements keeping the user story safe